# change order of filling in par(mfrow)

Tags: r, grid, fill

The default order to fill the grid is from left to right and from top to bottom, I would like to change it from top to bottom and from left to right, so instead of:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

I want:

```
1 3 5 7
2 4 6 8
```

where the numbers are the other in which the grid is filled.

Thanks.

Comment: `par(mfcol = c(2, 4))`